# Workbench moderation and Views

Tags: panels, workbench

I have a content type which is being managed by [Workbench Moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation). This content type has entity reference field. The full page override has been Panelized and has a view pane which displays fields from the referenced entity.

When viewing the published content this all works fine, however, when viewing the 'draft' version of the content using Workbench Moderation the View Pane is obviously only using references from the published revision with the consequence that editors cannot see the affects of their changes, ie adding additional references.

How can I configure the View pane so that it will always list the the referenced entities from the currently viewed revision?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are possibily nightmares trying to get Panelizer or IPE and Workbench Moderation to play nice together. I've used both seperately, but not together on 1 site when using Moderation.

See this issue thread for Panelizer and Moderation for possible solutions:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1402860